# What is the wrong with my CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I am building an theme with html and css but not working. Why the background color is not showing ? What is the wrong CSS code? I cannot find the error that is making problem. Can anyone help me to fix it?

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
}
#main-header {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#main-header h1 {
  float: left;
}
#main-header nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section id="main-header">
    <h1>SITE NAME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>SERVICE</li>
        <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: **Clear** your floats... http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Your header has 0 height because of the floated elements.

Comment: Yes , Thats the Height was problem .Thanks

Comment: Daib, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599811/why-have-empty-content-on-css-after#answer-9599964 in answer to your question below

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the floating elements. This means you have to put an element with `clear:both` CSS property after your floating ones. I recommend using the [::after pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```
#main-header::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

This will automatically clear your floats without requiring you to create additional elements.

Comment: What is content: **' ';** ??

Comment: Content is necessary to give a "body" to pseudo-elements (such as `::after`), otherwise they won't render. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overflow` css property (`auto`, for example) to clear the `float` height effect :

```
header { overflow:auto; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq6fnvze/)

Answer (score 2):

Since your container contains floating element, its height is equal to zero, unless you will set the `height` or `min-height` via CSS, that *is not* an optimal solution. Below  are explained all the known solutions to clear floating elements:

### The safe and traditional manner: float (all!) container(s)

In this case, you make all the containers of the floating element likewise floating itself, and setting the `width,` like this:

```
header {
 background-color: blue;
 float:left;
}

#main-header nav {
  float: right;
  background:red;
  width:50%
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/winuho/2/edit)

The pitfall is that it affects the layout, you have to handle it applying the float to all parents, endless waterfall-like CSS ensues...

### The backward-looking way: clear with non-semantic element

You can clear the float inserting a void element before the closing tag of the parent, like this:

```
  [CSS]
   .clear-all {clear:both;}

  [HTML]
  <header>
   .....
   <span class="clear-all"></span>
  </header>
```

The pitfall is that the `span` element, or whatever, is not semantic.

### The quick and dirty way: Overflow: hidden

Setting `overflow: hidden` to the parent/container, it makes it to define its boundaries.
The pitfall is that if your layoud must have element the overlap the container, you can't afford it.

### The modern way: clearfix:after

By reading this [Css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) article, you can learn that:

> The Easy Clearing Method uses a clever CSS pseudo selector (:after) to clear floats. Rather than setting the overflow on the parent, you apply an additional class like "clearfix" to it. Then apply this CSS:

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
 }
```

That is in my opinion the best, concise, restrained way to clear floats.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have any unfloated element to "build" the height inside the header, and the height is not specifically defined.

Here's what happens when you define it:

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
}
#main-header {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#main-header h1 {
  float: left;
}
#main-header nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section id="main-header">
    <h1>SITE NAME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>SERVICE</li>
        <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following Two options:

```
header { 
 ...
 overflow:auto; 
 min-height:10px; /*or what vere you thing would be ideal for default*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using floating elements, so the parent element, in this case header, will have a zero height value, what you need to do is to add another element to clear the floats, for example like this:

One more thing, defining a header height will also solve the problem, but it's a bad practice, especially if you are dealing with responsive layouts, or if you need to add or remove some content inside header latter.

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
}
#main-header {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#main-header h1 {
  float: left;
}
#main-header nav {
  float: right;
}
.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section id="main-header">
    <h1>SITE NAME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>SERVICE</li>
        <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</header>
```