# Why do I need content when using some icon fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, icons, material-design, ligature

I am used to using Google Material icons, to do this I typically include it like this...

```
// Pug
link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons&display=block", rel="stylesheet")
```

Inside that is code like this...

```
// css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

However, I am using another font icon file and I try to do it the same way but it fails. After some investigation it seems to require an explicit declaration like this...

```
.ico_thing:before {
  content: "\E000";
}
```

Notice how the Google package is not explicitly defining the content. Why is this explicitly defined in this library and not in Material?

Comment: to display anything with `before` you have to use `content` read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599811/why-do-i-need-an-empty-content-property-on-an-after-pseudo-element

Comment: I get that but why don't I need it with google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Material Icons library doesn't rely on the `content` attribute in pseudoclasses, and in fact doesn't have any explicit CSS for each icon.  You can see this by inspecting the example code in their documentation (note the highlighted element):

[image]
[image]

As they explain, this is thanks to using [ligatures](https://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts/):

> This example uses a typographic feature called ligatures, which allows rendering of an icon glyph simply by using its textual name. The replacement is done automatically by the web browser and provides more readable code than the equivalent numeric character reference.

Other icon libraries, as you noted, use explicit declarations with `content` rather than ligatures, mostly to maintain support with older browsers (such as IE 9 and lower). The downside is larger CSS files.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am trying to understand do you have more links about this? (missed link but any info is awesome)

Comment: Sure, here's a few helpful links: https://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts/ - and - https://css-tricks.com/ligature-icons/

Comment: What is the content string called (if the other is a ligature)? The "\E000"

Comment: ISO numeric codes: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/